# Loop through a nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm looking for a solution to loop through a nested JSON object in pure JS.
Indeed I'd like to console.log every item and each of its properties.

```
const json_object = 
{
    "item1":{
        "name": "apple",
        "value": 2,
    },

    "item2":{
        "name": "pear",
        "value": 4,
    }
}

for(let item in json_object){
    console.log("ITEM = " + item);

    for(let property in json_object[item]){
        console.log(?); // Here is the issue
    }
}
```

Comment: `json_object[item][property]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing an object's value using its key in `json_object[item]` so just keep drilling down into the object.

```
for(let item in json_object){
    console.log("ITEM = " + item);

    for(let property in json_object[item]){
        console.log(json_object[item][property]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe also log `property`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const json_object = 
    {
       "item1":{
          "name": "apple",
          "value": 2,
       },

       "item2":{
         "name": "pear",
         "value": 4,
        }
    };

    for(let item in json_object){
        console.log("ITEM = " + item);

        for(let property in json_object[item]){
          console.log(`key:${property}, value:${json_object[item][property]}`);
       }
    }
```